# I ain't able to find the error after a lot of trial and error on Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNCrl.png)

Here's the image. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Someone just downvoted your question.  To see why they did that read about asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Do that then edit/revise your question and hopefully someone will then be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets on line 70 instead of parentheses.